# How do I properly use a select box with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select box for the event types of an event. event belongs to event_type and event_type has many events. Here's what I have for the select box:

```
<%= f.select :event_type, options_from_collection_for_select(EventType.all, :id, :name, @event.id), :placeholder => 'Select an event type' %>
```

But, the problem is that when I submit it, it submits the id of the event type and not the name of it. So, how would I make it submit the name rather than the id? If you need to see the any more code than just tell me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the id after the submit to load the event type again in your controller post action like this:

```
selected_type = EventType.find(params[:event_type]
```

It is also a good practice to keep database calls to the controller, so please put the `EventType.all` statement in there and pass it as local or class variable like you did with `event`.

If you really want to pass the name in your form instead of the id, you can replace the `:id` part in your call to something more like this `options_from_collection_for_select(@event_types, :name, :name, @event.event_type.name)`. Keep in mind that this value should be unique!

The method works like this:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)
```

So the first parameter contains all the options, the second defines the value within those option objects which are put into the `value` field of the HTML option (which is being submitted by the form), the third defines the text which is displayed to the user and the final parameter defines the `value` of the selected entry (in case you are editing an entry for example). For the last parameter, you need to use the events' event_type id, or in your case, the name because you set the `value` of your HTML tag to it.

Use pages like ApiDock or the Rails tutorials to get examples for some of these methods.
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select

Comment: Thanks for the help! would I put selected_type in the create action?

Comment: The selected_type should actually be one of the values of your event since your event ought to know what type it is. It should have a relation to the event_type class (using `belongs_to` and `has_many` respectively), so you can access it using `@event.event_type.id`. If  that's done, then yes, use it in the create action when initiating the event object or when editing as well.

Comment: If the relation is set up properly, use this snippet to make your life easier: `<%= f.select :event_type_id, @event_types.map{|t| [t.name, t.id]} %>`. This should automatically select the right option when editing and also enable you to create the object including the relation in the action using `Event.create(params[:event])`. You can still do it manually using the info from my post though.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter to `options_from_collection_for_select` is the value that will be submitted with the form. You have `:id`, so change it to `:name`.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select

(but this seems like a strange thing to do - typically you would store the event type ID.)

Comment: Agreed, normally you want to store the id from the select box to persist the user's choice to the db. If you also need the name, you can always use the id to look up the name from the db. One reason to do things this way is it allows you to change the names of your event types without messing up existing records.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass name in the Value method, if you want to pass the name,

```
<%= f.select :event_type, options_from_collection_for_select(EventType.all, :name, :name, @event.id), :placeholder => 'Select an event type' %>
```

Here is the doc for [options_from_collection_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)